# Can I I manually edit the records dnsmaq offers?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I use **dnsmasq** to provide DHCP to the household and to cache DNS records (and an odd TFTP)

Now I'm trying to debug a fetchmail config file and I noticed my mailhost appears to have a broken server (or a bad entry) fetchmail was taking 5 minutes to respond to a poll and with verbose showed it was timing out.

```
mail@ybox:/var/log$ fetchmail -vv -f /etc/fetchmailrc.test -d0
Old UID list from imap.forwardemail.net:
<empty>

Scratch list of UIDs:
<empty>

fetchmail: 6.4.16 querying imap.forwardemail.net (protocol IMAP) at Sat 03 Feb 2024 18:58:51 GMT: poll started
Trying to connect to 2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001/993...connection failed.
fetchmail: connection to imap.forwardemail.net:imaps [2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001/993] failed: Connection timed out.
Trying to connect to 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec/993...connected.
fetchmail: Loaded OpenSSL library 0x1010117f newer than headers 0x101010bf, trying to continue.
```

Pinging the servers seems to show one the two is down...can I somehow edit out the "bad one"  ...and preferably have it reappear after some time (e.g. TTL)

```
mail@ybox:/var/log$ nslookup 
> set querytype=aaaa
> imap.forwardemail.net
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   imap.forwardemail.net
Address: 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec
Name:   imap.forwardemail.net
Address: 2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001

mail@ybox:/var/log$ ping 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec
PING 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec(2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=148 ms
64 bytes from 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=148 ms
  C-c C-c
--- 2001:19f0:ac00:45f3:5400:4ff:fe9c:dfec ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 147.205/147.674/148.115/0.372 ms
mail@ybox:/var/log$ ping 2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001
PING 2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001(2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001) 56 data bytes
  C-c C-c
--- 2a03:b0c0:2:d0::e83:6001 ping statistics ---
367 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 374782ms
```